# How do I list numbers in python from an external file?

Tags: python, file

the contents of the external file are like this:

```
Ricky, 12
Sachin, 45
Brian, 2
Monty, 1
```

What I basically want to do is to be able to read this in python and being able to order it, so it goes lowest scores at bottom and highest score at top.

Here is the code I got so far:

```
def SaveTopScores():
  return HiScores.rsplit('(',1)[1]

  with open("HiScores.txt", "r")as file:
    HiScoreslist = HiScores.read().splitlines()

  HiScoreslist.sort()

  HiScoreslist.sort(key=HiScore)

  for HiScore in HiScoreslist:
    print(HiScore)
```

I am still a novice at python and really do need help. Please correct me where I am wrong and tell me if I am completely wrong and if so what is the best way for me to go about solving the problem?

Comment: Is the indentation correct? 'cause you're `return`ing right at the first line of the function body, and the rest is never executed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) and I think it's correct. I done a practice of this by doing a similar type of thing in which i ordered film years from a film list and it worked. So now I'm confused? if you think there is a better way of doing it please show me how. I don't know what to do. :(

Comment: you do an rsplit, searching for a left parenthesis. That character is not in the input file, so why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some list comprehensions:

```
with open("HiScores.txt") as hiscores:
    scores = [line.split(',') for line in hiscores if line.strip()]
scores = [(name.strip(), int(score)) for name, score in scores]
scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[1], reversed=True)

for name, score in scores:
    print('{:<20} {:>10}'.format(name, score))
```

This:

1. opens the file as a context manager (`with ... as ...`) so it is automatically closed
2. loops over the file splitting each line (provided the line is not empty)
3. turns each 2-value entry in the file into a stripped string and a integer
4. sorts the file on the second value in each tuple (the score), reversing the result (highest score first)
5. prints each entry formatted (align each name to the left in a 20-character area, each score to the right in a 10-character field).

Comment: (+1) for checking for empty lines :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, somewhat like this?

```
def scores(fn):

    data = []
    with open(fn) as f:
        for ln in f:
            name, score = ln.strip().split(',')
            data.append((int(score.strip()), name))

    for score, name in sorted(data, reversed=True):
        print name, score
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your original code too much, this should work.  Let me know if you need any parts explained.

```
with open("HiScores.txt", "r") as fin:
    HiScores = fin.read().splitlines()

HiScoresList = []

for score in HiScores:
    name, score = score.split(', ')
    score = int(score.strip())
    HiScoresList.append((name, score))

# Look at two score entries, and compare which score is larger
def BestScore(a, b):
   return cmp(b[1], a[1])

HiScoresList.sort(BestScore)

for HiScore in HiScoresList:
    print(HiScore)
```

Prints:

```
('Sachin', 45)
('Ricky', 12)
('Brian', 2)
('Monty', 1)
```

Comment: Thank-you for response. and well I sort of understand how that works and well could you explain to me what 'fin' is please?.

Comment: The syntax for `with` is `with function_returning_file_object() as variable_to_hold_file_object:`.  I just call my variables, in this case, `fin` or `fout` for "file-input" or "file-output".  It's easier than thinking up creative names for a variable you only need for one line of code.  Call it anything you like :-)  Just make sure that you call `.read()` on the same variable.